# Machine redable FHIR mappings and formal definitions?

Tags: hl7-fhir

The formal definitions (for example [patient definitions](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient-definitions.html)) and the mappings (for example [patient mappings](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient-mappings.html)) would be even more useful if they were in an easily processed format (CSV, rdb, etc). Is it necessary to scrape that information out of the HTML, or can it be downloaded?  I don't see it on the FHIR downloads page (or discussed on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

The complete processible form is http://hl7.org/fhir/profiles-resources.xml.
Or there's the schema http://hl7.org/fhir/fhir-all-xsd.zip.

In future versions, there'll also be RDF, and ISO 11179 related representations.